# Setting a declared variable to 2 concatenated columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, concatenation

I am trying to combine the values from 2 columns from one table(`ApplicationUsers` is the table and the columns are`UserFirstName` and `UserLastName`) into a single variable called `UserName`. Nothing I do seems to be working.My goal is to insert this new variable into another table. I've tried multiple approaches but this is the ltest (it fails)

```
 DECLARE @UserFirstName nvarchar(250)
 DECLARE @UserLastName nvarchar(250)
 DECLARE @UserName nvarchar(250)
 DECLARE @Role nvarchar = Null
 DECLARE @AppUserName nvarchar(250) = 'jbrown'

 SELECT AppUserName, (CAST(UserFirstName as Nvarchar(250)) + ' ' + 
 CAST(UserLastName as Nvarchar(250))) AS @UserName
 FROM ApplicationUsers
 WHERE @AppUserName = AppUserName
```

I keep getting an `Invalid column` on `UserFirstName` and `UserLastName`. I've also tried this, but it basically selects nothing. What am I doing wrong here? My goal is to have `@UserName = 'John Brown'`

```
 SELECT AppUserName, UserFirstName, UserLastName
 FROM ApplicationUsers
 WHERE @AppUserName = AppUserName
 AND @UserFirstName = UserFirstName
 AND @UserLastName = UserLastName
 AND @UserName = UserFirstName + ' ' + UserLastName
 Print @UserName
```

Note: If I just use the following, it selects the correct row/record from the table -

```
SELECT AppUserName, UserFirstName, UserLastName
FROM ApplicationUsers
WHERE @AppUserName = AppUserName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `CONCAT()` instead :

```
SELECT @UserName = CONCAT(UserFirstName, ' ', UserLastName)  
FROM ApplicationUsers
WHERE AppUserName = @AppUserName;
```

If one of them (i.e. `UserFirstName`, `UserLastName`) has `null` value then entire field would be `null`. So, `CONCAT()` implicitly converts `null` values to empty strings.

If `CONCAT()`  is not support then use `ISNULL()` instead & then do concatenation :

```
SELECT @UserName = ISNULL(UserFirstName, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(UserLastName, '')  
FROM ApplicationUsers
WHERE AppUserName = @AppUserName;
```

This assumes `AppUserName` has not mutilple rows if not then use `DISTINCT` OR `TOP (1)` clause.

Comment: Arghh! I'm getting `'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name!`

Comment: `CONCAT()` will ignore the NULLs and treat them as empty strings.